# Wait for an UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, asynchronous, camera

I have this code in AVCamCaptureManager:

```
- (void) captureStillImage
{
AVCaptureConnection *stillImageConnection = [AVCamUtilities connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[[self stillImageOutput] connections]];
if ([stillImageConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
    [stillImageConnection setVideoOrientation:orientation];

[[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection
                                                     completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

                                                         ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock completionBlock = ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                                             if (error) {
                                                                 if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManager:didFailWithError:)]) {
                                                                     [[self delegate] captureManager:self didFailWithError:error];
                                                                     }
                                                             }
                                                         };

                                                         if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
                                                             NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                                                             //ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

                                                             //UIImage *imagePhoto = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                                                             /*
                                                             [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage]
                                                                                       orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation]
                                                                                   completionBlock:completionBlock];*/
                                                             self.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData]; 

                                                             //[imagePhoto release];

                                                             //[library release];
                                                         }
                                                         else
                                                             completionBlock(nil, error);

                                                         if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManagerStillImageCaptured:)]) {
                                                             [[self delegate] captureManagerStillImageCaptured:self];
                                                         }
                                                     }];
}
```

and this methos in another class

```
- (IBAction)captureStillImage:(id)sender
{
// Capture a still image
//[[self stillButton] setEnabled:NO];
[[self captureManager] captureStillImage];

if ([captureManager image] == nil) NSLog(@"image nil");

[preview setImage:[captureManager image]];
[snap setAlpha:0.00];
[use setAlpha:1.00];
[retake setAlpha:1.00];
```

my problem is that when I call the IBAction I have ever image = nil because I have the other method in AsynchronouslyFromConnection; what can I do to solve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your example the AVCamCaptureManager can be passed a delegate.
When it has finished capturing the image it calls captureManagerStillImageCaptured: on the delegate. When the delegates method is fired you can do that work i.e.

```
-(void)captureManagerStillImageCaptured:(id)sender
{
[preview setImage:[captureManager image]];
[snap setAlpha:0.00];
[use setAlpha:1.00];
[retake setAlpha:1.00];

}
```

If you do not understand how delegates work then i suggest searching on here or asking another question.

[Delegate Tutorial](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/delegates/how-to-create-a-delegate)